# CheckBox based WPF TreeView is reflecting its state only once after loading not in subsequent state change events

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, treeview

here is the screenshot of UI
[image]

the problem is if my whole tree is collapsed and i check the root element then after expanding child elements I can see they are checked but now if I will uncheck or check root elements then there will be no effect or change in the checked state of child elements..

I have created a following type of TreeView in my WPF application.
Although I have not followed MVVM strictly but still binded my WPF TreeView using XAMl shown below.

```
 <TreeView  Grid.Row="0" Height="485" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" Background="Transparent" Name="tree" SelectedItemChanged="OnTreeViewNodeSelected">
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsInitiallySelected, Mode=OneTime}" />
                                                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
                                                <Setter Property="uc:VirtualToggleButton.IsVirtualToggleButton" Value="True" />
                                                <Setter Property="uc:VirtualToggleButton.IsThreeState" Value="True" />
                                                <Setter Property="uc:VirtualToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <TreeView.Resources>
                                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type self:Solution}" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="Visual Studio Solution">
                                                    <CheckBox Click="OnCheckBoxClicked" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <Image Source="../Images/Solution.png" Height="16" Width="16"  Margin="5"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SolutionName}" FontSize="16"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type self:Project}" ItemsSource="{Binding Files, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="Visual Studio Project">
                                                    <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked , Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <Image Source="../Images/Project.png" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="5"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProjectName}" FontSize="16"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type self:File}" ItemsSource="{Binding Classes, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="File">
                                                        <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked , Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <Image Source="../Images/File.png" Margin="5" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" FontSize="16"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type self:Class}" ItemsSource="{Binding Methods, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="Class">
                                                        <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked , Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <Image Source="../Images/Class.png" Margin="5" Height="16" Width="16" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ClassName}" FontSize="16" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Method}">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="Method">
                                                        <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked , Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <Image Source="../Images/Method.png" Margin="5" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MethodName}" FontSize="16"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </TreeView.Resources>
                                    </TreeView>
```

Here is another Utility file which I referenced in setters at the top of Xaml
this is standard reusable file , I dont think anything wrong is here in this file

```
public static class VirtualToggleButton
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", typeof(Nullable<bool>), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Nullable<bool>)false,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsCheckedChanged)));


        public static Nullable<bool> GetIsChecked(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (Nullable<bool>)d.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
        }


        public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject d, Nullable<bool> value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        }


        private static void OnIsCheckedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement pseudobutton = d as UIElement;
            if (pseudobutton != null)
            {
                Nullable<bool> newValue = (Nullable<bool>)e.NewValue;
                if (newValue == true)
                {
                    RaiseCheckedEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
                else if (newValue == false)
                {
                    RaiseUncheckedEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
                else
                {
                    RaiseIndeterminateEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
            }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsThreeStateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsThreeState", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)false));


        public static bool GetIsThreeState(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsThreeStateProperty);
        }


        public static void SetIsThreeState(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsThreeStateProperty, value);
        }



        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsVirtualToggleButton", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)false,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsVirtualToggleButtonChanged)));


        public static bool GetIsVirtualToggleButton(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty);
        }


        public static void SetIsVirtualToggleButton(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnIsVirtualToggleButtonChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IInputElement element = d as IInputElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    element.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
                    element.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
                }
                else
                {
                    element.MouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
                    element.KeyDown -= OnKeyDown;
                }
            }
        }

        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseCheckedEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null) return null;

            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs();
            args.RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.CheckedEvent;
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseUncheckedEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null) return null;

            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs();
            args.RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.UncheckedEvent;
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseIndeterminateEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null) return null;

            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs();
            args.RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.IndeterminateEvent;
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        private static void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);
        }

        private static void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource == sender)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Space)
                {
                    // ignore alt+space which invokes the system menu
                    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt) return;

                    UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);
                    e.Handled = true;

                }
                else if (e.Key == Key.Enter && (bool)(sender as DependencyObject).GetValue(KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturnProperty))
                {
                    UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateIsChecked(DependencyObject d)
        {
            Nullable<bool> isChecked = GetIsChecked(d);
            if (isChecked == true)
            {
                SetIsChecked(d, GetIsThreeState(d) ? (Nullable<bool>)null : (Nullable<bool>)false);
            }
            else
            {
                SetIsChecked(d, isChecked.HasValue);
            }
        }

        private static void RaiseEvent(DependencyObject target, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (target is UIElement)
            {
                (target as UIElement).RaiseEvent(args);
            }
            else if (target is ContentElement)
            {
                (target as ContentElement).RaiseEvent(args);
            }
        }    
    }
```

Here is the Code Behind File Screen.xaml.cs

```
Solution sol = roslynService.GetSolution();
tree.Items.Clear();
 ICollection<Solution> rootCollection = new ObservableCollection<Solution>();
rootCollection.Add(sol);
tree.ItemsSource = rootCollection;
```

and here are my Models where I  mainly wrote code to check all child of any checked tree view item.

```
public class Solution
    {

        private bool? _isChecked = false;
        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set { this.SetIsChecked(value, true); }
        }

        public String LogNamespace { get; set; }
        public String LogClassName { get; set; }

        public string SolutionPath { get; set; }

        public string SolutionName { get; set; }

        public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }

        public void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren)
        {
            if (value == _isChecked)
                return;

            _isChecked = value;

            if (updateChildren && _isChecked.HasValue)
                this.Projects.ForEach(p => p.SetIsChecked(_isChecked, true, false));

            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }

        public void VerifyCheckState()
        {
            bool? state = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Projects.Count; ++i)
            {
                bool? current = this.Projects[i].IsChecked;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    state = current;
                }
                else if (state != current)
                {
                    state = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.SetIsChecked(state, true);
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            foreach (Project child in this.Projects)
            {
                child._solution = this;
                child.Initialize();
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public Solution _solution;

        private bool? _isChecked = false;
        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set { this.SetIsChecked(value, true, true); }
        }
        public ProjectId ProjectId { get; set; }

        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        public List<File> Files { get; set; }

        public void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent)
        {
            if (value == _isChecked)
                return;

            _isChecked = value;

            if (updateChildren && _isChecked.HasValue)
                this.Files.ForEach(f => f.SetIsChecked(_isChecked, true, false));

            if (updateParent)
                _solution.VerifyCheckState();

            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }

        public void VerifyCheckState()
        {
            bool? state = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Files.Count; ++i)
            {
                bool? current = this.Files[i].IsChecked;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    state = current;
                }
                else if (state != current)
                {
                    state = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.SetIsChecked(state, false, true);
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            foreach (File child in this.Files)
            {
                child._project = this;
                child.Initialize();
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }

    public class File
    {
        public Project _project;

        private bool? _isChecked = false;
        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set { this.SetIsChecked(value, true, true); }
        }
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public string FileType { get; set; }

        public string FileId { get; set; }

        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }

        public void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent)
        {
            if (value == _isChecked)
                return;

            _isChecked = value;

            if (updateChildren && _isChecked.HasValue)
                this.Classes.ForEach(c => c.SetIsChecked(_isChecked, true, false));

            if (updateParent && _project != null)
                _project.VerifyCheckState();

            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }

        public void VerifyCheckState()
        {
            bool? state = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Classes.Count; ++i)
            {
                bool? current = this.Classes[i].IsChecked;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    state = current;
                }
                else if (state != current)
                {
                    state = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.SetIsChecked(state, false, true);
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            foreach (Class child in this.Classes)
            {
                child._file = this;
                child.Initialize();
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }

    public class Class
    {
        public File _file;

        private bool? _isChecked = false;
        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set { this.SetIsChecked(value, true, true); }
        }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }

        public List<Method> Methods { get; set; }
        public void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent)
        {
            if (value == _isChecked)
                return;

            _isChecked = value;

            if (updateChildren && _isChecked.HasValue)
                this.Methods.ForEach(m => m.SetIsChecked(_isChecked, false));

            if (updateParent && _file != null)
                _file.VerifyCheckState();

            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }

        public void VerifyCheckState()
        {
            bool? state = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Methods.Count; ++i)
            {
                bool? current = this.Methods[i].IsChecked;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    state = current;
                }
                else if (state != current)
                {
                    state = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.SetIsChecked(state, false, true);
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            foreach (Method child in this.Methods)
            {
                child._class = this;
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }

    public class Method
    {
        public Class _class;

        private bool? _isChecked = false;
        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set { this.SetIsChecked(value, true); }
        }
        public string MethodName { get; set; }
        public string AccessSpecifier { get; set; }
        public string MethodBody { get; set; }

        public void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateParent)
        {
            if (value == _isChecked)
                return;

            _isChecked = value;

            if (updateParent && _class != null)
                _class.VerifyCheckState();

            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
}
```

I have referred solution given in this blog
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-checkbox-control/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by updated List to ObservableCollection and inherited each Model class by INotifyPropertyChanged